# How should i set the FOR attributes for this controller group to optimize accessabilty?

Tags: html, accessibility

How should i set the FOR attributes for this controller group to optimize accessabilty?

The inputs are mutually exclusive, either you have an amount or a customamount.
The doctype is HTML5.

```
<div class="inputRow">
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="50" class="preset_amount" checked="checked" />
    <label>50</label>            
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="100" class="preset_amount" />
    <label>100</label>
    <input type="radio" name="amount" value="150" class="preset_amount" />
    <label>150</label>
</div>

<div class="inputRow">      
    <input id="customamount" name="customamount" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo _('custom amount') ?>" <?php getValue("customamount") ?> />
    <label for="customamount"><?php echo _("or choose a custom amount") ?></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="inputRow">
    <input type="radio" id="present_amount_50" name="amount" value="50" class="preset_amount" checked="checked" />
    <label for="present_amount_50">50</label>            
    <input type="radio" id="present_amount_100" name="amount" value="100" class="preset_amount" />
    <label for="present_amount_100">100</label>
    <input type="radio" id="present_amount_150" name="amount" value="150" class="preset_amount" />
    <label for="present_amount_150">150</label>
</div>

<div class="inputRow">      
    <input id="customamount" name="customamount" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo _('custom amount') ?>" <?php getValue("customamount") ?> />
    <label for="customamount"><?php echo _("or choose a custom amount") ?></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Does anybody have a decent explaination of what the last sentance in the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-for) really means?

"This attribute explicitly associates the label being defined with another control. When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents."

Comment: `<label for="foo">Foo</label><input id="foo">` means the same as `<label>Foo<input>`

Answer (score 1):

Set the `id`-Attribute for every control, then use `<label for="{controlId}">..</label>` like this:

```
<div class="inputRow">
    <input id="rb1" type="radio" name="amount" value="50" class="preset_amount" checked="checked" />
    <label for="rb1">50</label>            
    ...
</div>
```